# Mutli-language, i18n, multilingual - addon suggestions?

Tags: add-on, multi-language, multilingual

I'm building a EE site and the front end needs to support multiple languages.

Requirements:

- control panel does not need to support multiple languages
  Needs translations:
- static content in the front end
- MAYBE the channel entries (not a strong requirement)
- field labels need translations
- having a segment in the URL indicating the language might be useful. It would be good if the language segment allows for something like "en-us", "en-uk", etc. and not just "en"

Any addon suggestions? Looking for suggestions from people that have actually used such addons. Also, any tips on "gotchas" would be helpful.

**Some Addons I've Found**

1. Publisher, $175 (Honorable Mention, 2012 New Module of the Year), latest update September 9, 2013
2. Transcribe, $150, latest update October 17, 2012

Comment: Easy languages or complex? e.g. Chinese, Arabic, Russian versus German, Spanish, French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publisher](http://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher) - it offers the most flexibility - especially in having URLs relative to the language (good for native users and for SEO), easy toggling between language entries. This also neatly handles rewriting for custom language identifiers in the URL.

Although you can roll your own solution, using tips and tricks found elsewhere and something like [Republic Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/republic-variables) to store your variables.

Here's a few older posts of approaches if you decide to do it yourself:

Carl describes how to create the language specific root segments in your URL via language folders and additional index.php files:
http://cwcrawley.co.uk/2010/01/multi-lingual-websites-in-expressionengine/

- http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site/
- http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine
- http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/161746/
- https://speakerdeck.com/u/stevieg_83/p/intro-to-multi-lingual-sites-in-expressionengine
- http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192

Taken from [my blog post](http://peteralewis.com/blog/expressionengine-multi-language/) regarding complex language translation (written prior to Publisher being released), but I would highly recommend using Publisher and save yourself the grief.